# javascript - insert into multidimensional array with for loop

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a sample array, `arr = [5,4,3,3,2,2,1]` and i need to generate a multidimensional array like that:

```
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
    )
 [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
    )
 [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 3
    )
 [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 2
    )
 [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )
```

I'm not sure about how javascript array works. I've tried to write the code but ended up the all the new array elements is `1`

```js
var arr = [5,4,3,3,2,2,1]
var arrtemp = []
var temp = []
var tempval = 0
var col = 0


for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  if (i==0) {
    temp.push(arr[i])
    tempval = arr[i]
  }
  
  else {
    if (arr[i] == tempval){
      temp.push(arr[i]);
    }
    else {
      arrtemp[col] = temp;
      col++;
      temp.length =0;
      temp.push(arr[i]);
      tempval = arr[i];
    }
  }
}

console.log(arrtemp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, your `arr` is already sorted. I'd use `reduce` instead, where the accumulator is an array of arrays. If the last array in the accumulator doesn't have the same value as the new item you're iterating over, create a new array in it, and push to the last array in the accumulator:

```js
var arr = [5,4,3,3,2,2,1];
const output = arr.reduce((a, num) => {
  if (!a.length || a[a.length - 1][0] !== num) {
    a.push([]);
  }
  a[a.length - 1].push(num);
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1];
let newArr = [[]];
let curVal = 0;
let col = 0;

curVal = arr[0];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] != curVal) {
    col++;
    newArr.push([]);
    curVal = arr[i];
  }
  newArr[col].push(curVal);
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `.join()` the array to form a string. Then on the string, you can match consecutive runs of numbers using `.match()` with regex. Lastly, you can `.split()` each match into an array.

See example below:

```js
const arr = [5,4,3,3,2,2,1];
const str = arr.join('').match(/(.)\1*/g).map(v => v.split(''));
             
console.log(str);
```

If your result must be numbers you can add an additional `.map()` to convert each string into a number:

```js
const arr = [5,4,3,3,2,2,1];
const str = arr.join('')
             .match(/(.)\1*/g)
             .map(v => v.split('').map(Number));
             
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
let arr = [5,4,3,3,2,2,1];
let last;
let newArr =[];
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  if (last!=arr[i]) {
    let temp=[];
    temp.push(arr[i]);
    newArr.push(temp);
    last =arr[i];
  }
  else
  {
    newArr[newArr.length-1].push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(newArr);
```